# exception error in program

Tags: c++

```
int maxNum(int *n)
{
    int Maximum = n[0];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        if( Maximum < n[i] )
            Maximum = abs(n[i]);
    }

    return Maximum;
}

void DibHomoginityDetect(CDib& dib)
{
    register int i,j,x[8];

    int w = dib.GetWidth();
    int h= dib.GetHeight();

    CDib cpy =dib;
    BYTE** ptr1 = dib.GetPtr();
    BYTE** ptr2 = cpy.GetPtr();

    for(j = 1;j<h-1;j++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<w-1;i++)
        {
            x[1]= (ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j-1][i-1]);
            x[2] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j-1][i]);
            x[3] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j-1][i+1]);
            x[4] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j][i-1]);
            x[5] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j][i+1]);
            x[6] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j+1][i-1]);
            x[7] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j+1][i]);
            x[8] =ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j+1][i+1];

            //assign the central pixel of window to image central pixel
            ptr1[j][i] = (BYTE)maxNum(x);
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong with this program.. as i understand it should work but i am getting exception error ...

Anyone can hellp  me that where did i make mistake .. .. thanks

Comment: Any chance you could fix the indentation to make this readable? And perhaps explain what it is expected to do if you weren't running off the end of its buffers?

Comment: Vote to close because you just vomit a wall of code and expect us to debug it for you with no guidance or any indication where the error occured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of hard to tell from the code, but I guess your for-loop should really be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

Arrays in C++ are indexed from zero, not one.

Comment: @neil Buttterworth: at first i started my array from index 0,.. due to exception i started it from 1

Comment: all the `x[?]` assignments need to be looked over too.

Comment: @Miss Not a good idea to flail around when bug-fixing. Start it at zero.

Comment: ahh @mat.. i got your point.. let me handle this now ..

Comment: Starting the loop at 1 is okay (as the first value is assigned as the default maximum; just the comparison has to be changed to `i < 8` in addition to changing the indices on `x` in the other loop).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this caused the error:

```
for(j = 1;j<h-1;j++)
{
    for(i=1;i<w-1;i++)
    {
        x[1]= (ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j-1][i-1]);
        x[2] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j-1][i]);
        x[3] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j-1][i+1]);
        x[4] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j][i-1]);
            x[5] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j][i+1]);
        x[6] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j+1][i-1]);
        x[7] =(ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j+1][i]);
        x[8] =ptr2[j][i]-ptr2[j+1][i+1];


    //assign the central pixel of window to image central pixel
    ptr1[j][i] = (BYTE)maxNum(x);   

    }
}
```

It seems that x[1]...x[8] will always be the value when `i=w-2` and `j=h-2`

Comment: no ... i and j will work until i = w-1 and j = h-1 ..

Comment: @Miss x[1]..x[8] will be overwrite when i and j increase

Comment: `x[8]` is off the end of the array. `x` has eight elements, `x[0]` through `x[7]`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb oh, I overlooked that..it's a shame..